# How do I make a modal dialog prevent user interaction with any other application (until it's closed)

Tags: vb.net, model, dialog

I have a basic app that creates an Excel workbook and outputs some data. That all works fine, but the Excel workbook is hiding my forms.

I was under the impression that using the `ShowDialog()` method meant that the form was shown as a dialog model, and thus was always on top and prevented users from interacting with other programs until the form was closed.

Clearly I'm missing something, and according to [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the model dialog only sits on top for the application that created it. However, I'm sure I've achieved this before and would be grateful for some pointers.

```
Module Main

    Sub main()

        Dim objMainForm As New mainForm
        Dim objFinishForm As New finishForm
        Dim objCancelForm As New cancelForm

        objMainForm.ShowDialog()

        If objMainForm.bolShowFinish Then
            objFinishForm.ShowDialog()
        End If

        If objMainForm.bolShowCancelled Then
            objCancelForm.ShowDialog()
        End If

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do this many browsers have built in security to avoid 'hostage taking' you could create a really simple virus that will take hold and disallow and interaction with the computer :/

Comment: @Funkotron_King - Good point. I'm sure I've done something similar in the past though. Maybe it's to make the application just sit on to of, rather than prevent interaction with other applications.